# python stdout and stderr: Am confused how my file object get passed to when i didn't declare global

Tags: python, file-io, stdout, stderr, sys

I am having problem understand the `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`

The problem is how did the variable put get got into the cmd module?
My aim is to write a single function that would accept a string basically I am using it to write exception caught in my application to the screen and to a log file. I saw similar code somewhere so I decided to learn more by using the same example i saw which was a little different from my as the other person was writing to tow files simultaneously with just one function call.

**According to my understanding:**

The `cmd` module recieves a `string` which it then calls `output` module on the recieved `string`.
`output` module takes two arguements - (1 of its parameters must evalute to python standard input module object and second the a string) fine.
However, since `output` module calls `logs` module which does the printing or better still combines parameters by calling `write` function from python's standard output object passing it the `string` or text to be written.

Please if my explanation is not clear it means I am truely not understanding the whole process.

My questions is: How does `put` variable called outside the function got into the `cmd` module or any other module when I have commented it or not even called out?

**Please find code below**
`

```
import sys

def logs(prints, message):
    #global put
    #print prints
    prints.write(message)
    prints.flush()

def output(prints, message):
    #global put
    #logs(prints, content)
    logs(prints, message)


    #logs(put, via)
''' This is where the confusion is, how did put get into this function when i did
not declare it...'''
def cmd(message):
    #global put

    output(put, message)
    output(sys.stderr, message)

put = open('think.txt', 'w')

#print put, '000000000'

cmd('Write me out to screen/file')
put.close()
```

`

Comment: Well, i don't know why someone would down vote me, I wrote the code, with over 2 hours trying to understand things, if i did understand it, I wouldn't post this. Its clear I have done research and done lots of testing that is why you can see some comments. The question I asked is about how put get assigned in the cmd function. I asked it twice if you didn't notice. Anyway, someone answered it and its clear to me now... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the way that python handles scopes. When you execute the script, the *logs*, *output* and *cmd* functions are defined in the module namespace. Then `put = open('think.txt', 'w')` creates a variable called *put* in the module namespace.

When you call *cmd*, you are now executing in the function's local namespace. it is created when the function is called and destroyed when the function exits. When python hits the expression `output(put, message)`, it needs to resolve the names *output*, *put* and *message* to see what to do with them. The rules for a function are that python will look for the name in the local function namespace and then fall back to the global module namespace if the variable is not found.

So, python checks the function namespace for *output*, doesn't find anything, looks at the module namespace and finds that *output* refers to a function object. It then checks the function namespace for *put*, doesn't find anything, looks at the module namespace and finds that *put* refers to an open file object. Finally, it looks up *message*, finds it in the function namespace (the function parameters go into the function namespace) and off it goes.

Comment: Your explanation is correct and it has made me to understand what is going on thanks

Answer (score 1):

`put` is declared as a `global` variable, so when you access it from within `cmd`, it is accessing that `global` variable without you needing to declare it within the function.

For example, this code prints `5` for the same reason:

```
def foo():
    print "bar: {0}".format(bar)

bar = 5

foo()
```